# Filter list of objects with checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter a list by the `id` property with checkboxes based on the following data..

```
var events = [
  {
    person: {
      first_name: "Joe",
      last_name: "Smith",
      id: 1
    },
    something: "else"
  },
  {
    person: {
      first_name: "Jane",
      last_name: "Doe",
      id: 2
    },
    something: "else"
  },
  {
    person: {
      first_name: "Joe",
      last_name: "Smith",
      id: 1
    },
    something: "else"
  },
  {
    person: {
      first_name: "Jane",
      last_name: "Doe",
      id: 2
    },
    something: "else"
  },
];
```

And another object with a list of all people;

```
var people = [
  {
    first_name: "Joe",
    last_name: "Smith"
    id: 1
  },
  {
    first_name: "Jane",
    last_name: "Doe"
    id: 2
  },
];
```

So, the output of all the events would be:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='event in events'>
    {{ event.person.first_name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the checkboxes that represent each person would be:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='person in people'>
    {{ person.first_name }}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="filter(person.id)"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a checkbox, I expect to filter down the list based on `id`. So I use underscore to filter:

```
$scope.filter = function(personID) {
      $scope.events = _.filter($scope.events, function(value){
        return value.person.id === personID;
      });
 };
```

However, the filter works the first time, but when I toggle it off, I'd like all the values to reset. So the expected behavior would be:

```
1. On load, everyone appears on the screen
2. When I check the "Joe" checkbox, the list only shows "Joe"
3. When I uncheck the "Joe" checkbox, the list resets to all.
```

Answer (score 1):

## The problem of your code

The elements of `$scope.events` only decrease and never increase because of your code below.

```
$scope.events = _.filter($scope.events
```

## My suggestion

If you could accept to add `checked` attribute of person, it might work to achieve what you want.

In html.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='person in people'>
    {{ person.first_name }}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.checked" ng-change="filter()" />
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='event in events'>
    {{ event.person.first_name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In javascript.

```
function myctl($scope){
    $scope.people = [
        {
            first_name: "Joe",
            last_name: "Smith",
            id: 1,
            checked: true
        },
        {
            first_name: "Jane",
            last_name: "Doe",
            id: 2,
            checked: true
        }
    ];

    $scope.allevents = [
        {
            person: {
                first_name: "Joe",
                last_name: "Smith",
                id: 1
            },
            something: "else"
        },
        {
            person: {
                first_name: "Jane",
                last_name: "Doe",
                id: 2
            },
            something: "else"
        },
        {
            person: {
                first_name: "Joe",
                last_name: "Smith",
                id: 1
            },
            something: "else"
        },
        {
            person: {
                first_name: "Jane",
                last_name: "Doe",
                id: 2
            },
            something: "else"
        },
    ];

    $scope.filter = function(){
        $scope.events = _.filter($scope.allevents, function(event){
            var _person = _.find($scope.people, function(item){
                return item.id===event.person.id;
            });
            return _person.checked;
        });
    };

    $scope.filter();

}
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/wx2umj76/)